# How to delete a cookie on php?

Tags: php, cookies

I want to delete a existing cookie with this:

header2.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['logout1']))
    {
        unset($_COOKIE['hr']);
        setcookie("hr", "", time() -3600);
        header("Location: ../index.php");
        return true;
    } ?>
```

but cookies cannot be deleted. So what's the problem?

here's my

hr.php

```
 <?php 
 include "header2.php";
 $auth = $_COOKIE['hr'];
 header ("Cache-Control:no-cache");
 if(!$auth == "ok") 
 {
 header ("Location: ../index.php");
 }
 ?>
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"    style="background-color: #228B22">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 <li>
 <h4 style = "margin-top:18px; color:#fff;"> HR </h4>
 </li>
 <li>
 <button type="submit" name="logout1">logout</button>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps this is a copy from some of my code to delete a cookie

```
setcookie('hr', null, -1, '/');
```

Comment: I already did that but nothing happen, sorry for my english.

Comment: It's all cool. I would also check to ensure that the cookie you are deleting, is set to the same domain as the cookie you set. Where do you set your cookie?